# how do I create an inverse function to save in my mysql in eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want my function to save inverse values in my database, how do I do this?
I created a function, but it does not work, can anyone help me?

```
class DashboardController extends Controller
{

    private $text;

    public function index()
    {
        $this->text = Chav::first();
        $this->text->alugado;

        if( $this->text === 1){
            $this->text->alugado = 0;
            $this->text->save();
        }elseif( $this->text === 0){
            $this->text->alugado = 1;
            $this->text->save();
            }

            return view('text');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ternary (or negation if it's a boolean column) to update the value:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->text = Chav::first();

    $this->text->update([
        'alugado' => $this->text->alugado ? 0 : 1
    ]);

    // if the column is a boolean use negation
    // $this->text->update([
    //    'alugado' => !$this->text->alugado
    // ]);

    return view('text');
}
```